# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata'

Tags: angular

after upgrading to angular 13 when I run `ng test --code-coverage` I received the error:

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata'

Answer (score -2):

Update core-js to version >= 3.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).